# ASP.NET: jQuery Ajax result not defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this jQuery ajax:

```
        // ... omitted code ...

        var data = "{'TagName':'" + TagName + "'}";

        var resultSet = 0;

        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Webservices/TagWebServices.asmx/GetTagByTagName") %>',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (t)
            {
                resultSet = t.d;
            }
        });

        jQuery(this).after("<div style='color:#E3E3E3; margin-bottom:10px;'>" +
        resultSet.desc +
        "</div>" );

        // ... omitted code ...
```

The problem is that resultSet.desc always returns "undefined" BUT when I use Firebug and add a breaking point in the last line and then click (Continue) resultSet.desc works as expected.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: This is the first time I use jQuery ajax but that makes sense it was a stupid mistake from my part. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous by default.
You could try to set ajax request synchronous setting: `async:false,` but this is a bad way.

The way to go is to code your logic in the success callback function keeping ref on 'this' object.

```
var data = "{'TagName':'" + TagName + "'}";

        var resultSet = 0,
            that = this;

        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Webservices/TagWebServices.asmx/GetTagByTagName") %>',
            data: data,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (t)
            {
                resultSet = t.d;
                 jQuery(that).after("<div style='color:#E3E3E3; margin-bottom:10px;'>" +
                    resultSet.desc +
                    "</div>" );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

An ajax call is Asynchronous (by definition...). So you have to put the affectation in the success handler:

```
$.ajax({ ...
    success : function(t) {
        resultSet = t.d;
        jQuery(this).after("<div style='color:#E3E3E3; margin-bottom:10px;'>" +
            resultSet.desc +
        "</div>" );
    }
)};
```